# Why is resample much slower than pd.Grouper in a groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

As per [pandas documention](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling)

> resample() is a time-based groupby, followed by a reduction method on each of its groups.

However I have noticed a huge difference in performance when comparing the use of `resample` vs `pd.Grouper` in a groupby (in favor of `pd.Grouper`)

I have a dataframe where each line represents the value of a certain type (think a sensor) on a certain day. It looks like this:

```
date         type  value
2018-01-01   1     12
2018-01-02   1     14
....
2018-01-01   2     12
....
```

On that dataframe

```
df.set_index('DT').sort_index().groupby(['type']).resample('W').first()
```

and

```
df.groupby(['type', pd.Grouper(key='DT', freq='W')]).first()
```

do the exact same thing. However, on the example dataset below, the `resample` way is ~30 times slower than `pd.Grouper` method (this is consistent with what I observed on my real datasets).

Where does this drop in performance come from?

```
# Creating the frame
date_range = pd.date_range(start=dt.datetime(2017,1,1), end=dt.datetime(2025,12,31), freq='W')
to_concat = []
for val in range(1,100):
    frame_tmp = pd.DataFrame()
    frame_tmp['DT'] = date_range
    frame_tmp['type'] = val
    frame_tmp['value'] = np.random.randint(1, 6, frame_tmp.shape[0])
    to_concat.append(frame_tmp)

df = pd.concat(to_concat, ignore_index=True)

%%timeit 
df.set_index('DT').sort_index().groupby(['type']).resample('W').first()

%%timeit
df.sort_values('DT').groupby(['type', pd.Grouper(key='DT', freq='W')]).first()

# Checking that they are indeed equals
res_groupby = df.sort_values('DT').groupby(['type', pd.Grouper(key='DT', freq='W')]).first()
res_resample = df.set_index('DT').sort_index().groupby(['type']).resample('W').first()
pd.DataFrame.equals(res_groupby, res_resample[['value']] )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact they are **not** equivalent, the example is poorly designed. 
If instead you use `freq='14D'` in `date_range` then the frames won't be equivalent. `res_resample` will have rows with `NaN` (every other week) where `res_groupby` simply won't have them.

Indeed, it seems that resample is slower on equivalent cases but they are not the same thing, so cannot really compare.

Comment: Actually this is a weird behaviour of Grouper with multiple keys, see:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18971

Comment: Did you ever get more insight into this? I just did a similar comparison (in pandas 0.25.2) between `df.groupby.resample` and `pd.Grouper` (using a column to specify the times instead of setting it in the index beforehand) and saw massive speedup (71x), and `df_resample.equals(df_grouper)` returns `True` so I know my results aren't off with the Grouper-based approach either.  I need to do a bunch more stuff with `groupby.apply` that is very slow right now and I'm trying to see if Grouper has any tricks I can use for similar speedups with non-time-series grouping.

Comment: No beyond just finding the related issue, I havent investigated any further

Comment: adding the nans for the missing keys can be as simple as doing a reindex with the group key, and it'll still be faster. keys = df.index.round('14D'); df.groupby(keys)....reindex(keys)